# How can I reference a specific rect in a Bokeh plot?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm working on a plot with ornamentations that draw rectangles over the plot to highlight some sections.

I'd like to find a reference for a rect that is plotted on top so that i can move it, unrelated to the data plotted.  I can't seem to figure out how to do that.  If there were multiple glyphs how would I be able to reference each one?

Let's say that I had a number of highlight rectangles overlaying my plot. And my plot was plotted in rectangles, how would I know to find one of the highlights?

```js
x = [x*0.005 for x in range(0, 200)]
y = x      

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = figure(width=400, height=400, x_range=(0, 1), y_range=(0, 1))

plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

# the points to be plotted
x1 = .30
y1 = .30
w1 = .40
h1 = .20
 
# plotting the graph
plot.rect(x1, y1,w1,h1)

slider = Slider(start=0.1, end=4, value=1, step=.1, title="power")
slider.js_link('value', plot,'x1')
layout = column(slider, plot)

show(layout)
```

the js_link call doesn't find the x1 in the Rect under the plot structure.  plot.rect doesn't work of course.

How can I reference the rect?

Comment: Glyphs (i.e. `rect`) are factories for drawing lots of glyph *instances* on the screen, based on the data. There are not individual objects the correpond to individual instances drawn on the screen. The only way to "refer" to an instance drawn on the screen is by the integer index that corresponds to it in the data source. Your slider has float values, though, so it seem like you exepct to be able to do some kind of spatial indexing against those values? It's not really clear what you want to actually accomplish (big picture), you really need to provide more information about your actual goal.

Comment: thanks - i wrote more clarifying verbage into the quesiton,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As bigreddot mentioned in the comment, you can address the `rect` in the list of the renderers of you `plot` object. This depends on the order you addad the renderers. To connect the `x` value of the `rect` to a slider value you can use `plot.renderers[1].glyph`.

The example below gives you the opportunity to move the rect by changing the center with to sliders.

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.layouts import column
output_notebook()

x = [0, 1]
y = [0, 1]      

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = figure(width=400, height=400, x_range=(0, 1), y_range=(0, 1))

plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

# the points to be plotted
x1 = .30
y1 = .30
w1 = .40
h1 = .20
 
# plotting the graph
plot.rect(x1, y1,w1,h1)

slider_x = Slider(start=0.1, end=1, value=x1, step=.1, title="x")
slider_x.js_link('value', plot.renderers[1].glyph,'x')
slider_y = Slider(start=0.1, end=1, value=y1, step=.1, title="y")
slider_y.js_link('value', plot.renderers[1].glyph,'y')
layout = column(slider_x, slider_y, plot)

show(layout)
```

Comment: this really helps - if i had plotted the data points with rects would that affect this code?  I guess if I had four or five rects that were on top of the plot that I had added i could address them from the index there?

Comment: i kinda found it though i would not have got it without your help - thanks!  https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/first_steps/first_steps_2.html

Comment: Instead of using `plot.renderers[1]` which is fragile (the order of renderers is not technically specified in any way) you can instead use `renderer = plot.rect` instead, to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Also note that Bokeh has built-in edit tools in case that serves your need out of the box https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/tools.html#boxedittool